# Why did the Microsoft developers did not put T4MVC (or its working) in the core MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What [T4MVC](http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/) does makes complete sense to us.

It converts the simple string input into strongly typed input, which eases things for the developer.

Like this -

```
return View("foo");
```

to

```
return View(Views.foo);  // better (T4MVC)
```

What could be a reason as to why the MS people are NOT doing it this way?

Comment: Because the T4MVC project already performs this function?

Comment: They should implement Cobol while they're at it for MVC, Cobol makes complete sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, a side project of T4MVC was started a long time ago, but was stalled due to (at the time) breaking changes in the Roslyn compiler.

Luckily, the project was revived, and [R4MVC](https://github.com/T4MVC/R4MVC) has just released it's first alpha build, with more changes coming soon.

While the project works somewhat differently, and isn't using t4 templates, the end result is the same, and we're working to achieve feature parity with T4MVC in the near future.